# Замена всех слов

Tags: javascript

Есть такой кодик:

```
var text = 'Пётр Илья Вова Пётр Миша Илья Евгеша Пётр Илья';
var one = 'Пётр';
var elem = text.replace(one, '1');
```

Но оно заменяет всего лишь одно слово из предложения. Как мне сделать, что бы оно заменяло все слова из этого предложения? (`var one` это изменчивая переменная)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var text = 'Пётр Илья Вова Пётр Миша Илья Евгеша Пётр Илья';
var one = 'Пётр';
var two = new RegExp(one,'g');
var elem = text.replace(two, '1');
```

Comment: Думаю, стоит упомянуть об эскейпировании спец. символов при создании регулярного выражения ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev отличная мысль! Упомяните.

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = 'Пётр Илья Вова Пётр Миша Илья Евгеша Пётр Илья';
var one = 'Пётр';
var elem = text.split(one).join('1');
```